# What's the type of csv.Dictreader.fieldnames in python?

Tags: python, csv, type-hinting

I am trying to read a csv file and read the field names (top row of csv file) from it. I used csv.Dictreader to create a reader object and extracted the top row using the reader.fieldnames object. I know that reader.fieldnames will be a list of strings for the kind of csv files I will be using. However, pylance considers the possibility that reader.fieldnames will be None and considers reader.fieldnames to be non-subscriptable.

Here's my code

```
import sys
import tabulate
import csv
import typing

def main() -> None:
    menu: list[list[str]] = list()
    
    try:
        file: typing.TextIO
        with open(sys.argv[1]) as file:
            reader: csv.DictReader = csv.DictReader(file)
            headings: list[str] = reader.fieldnames
            row: dict[str,str]
            for row in reader:
                menu.append([row[headings[0]],row[headings[1]],row[headings[2]]])            
    except IOError:
        sys.exit("CSV file does not exist")
    else:
        print(tabulate.tabulate(menu, headers=headings, tablefmt="grid"))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

If I use the list[str] type for headings, pylance complaints that

`Expression of type "Sequence[Unknown] | None" cannot be assigned to declared type "list[str]"`

However, if I skip the type hint for headings, pylance complaints with headings[0] that

`Object of type "None" is not subscriptable`

How do I deal with this problem? I could ignore pylance warnings, but I do not want to do so, unless there is no solution to this problem.

Comment: Why are you using `DictReader` if you're just going to convert the dictionary to a list?

Comment: FYI: Looks like you should just use `reader = csv.reader(file)` and `headings = next(reader)`, then `for row in reader: menu.append(row)`.

Comment: Do type hints not work with dictreader? I just thought dictreader is a convenient way of organizing data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is to do a simple assert that heading is not None:

```py
try:
    with open("inpu.csv", newline="") as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)
        headings = reader.fieldnames
        assert headings is not None
        assert len(headings) == 3

        menu: list[list[str]] = []
        for row in reader:
            menu.append([row[headings[0]], row[headings[1]], row[headings[2]]])
except IOError as e:
    print(f"couldn't open CSV: {e}")
except AssertionError:
    print(
        f"couldn't get fieldnames, check CSV and ensure first line is a properly encoded row"
    )
else:
    print(menu)
```

If it fails, you'll know to look at the CSV file for any kind of issues.

- Before the assert, VSCode shows that headings could be `Sequence[str] | None`.
- After the assert, the type checker realizes that it cannot have been None, so headings must be `Sequence[str]`.

Also, look at Barmar's and Mark Tolonen's comments, you can do what you much more simply by just reading the CSV as a list of strings:

```py
reader = csv.reader(f)
menu = list(reader)[1:]

print(menu)
```

```py
[
    ["foo", "1", "a"],
    ["bar", "2", "b"],
    ["baz", "3", "c"],
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`fieldnames` can potentially be `None` if the CSV file is empty.

You can solve your problem by providing a default value.

```
headings: list[str] = reader.fieldnames or ["", "", ""]
```